# Create custom table with pagination

Tags: 8, database

I have a function in a controller which shows data in table format. I need pagination and styling for the table. I tried as follow.

#### MyController.php

```
public function my_requests() {       
        //load the current user details
        $user= User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
        $user_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();

        //Query the database
        $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
           ->tableSort($header)
           ->condition('status', 1)
           ->condition('type', "forward_proxy_request")
           ->condition('uid', $user_id)
           ->sort('nid' , 'ASC');
        $table_sort = $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender')->orderByHeader($header);
        $pager = $table_sort->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')->limit(10);
        $nids = $pager->execute();

        //creates the table header
        $header = [
                'Node id',
                'title',               
                'Name',
                'Ip',
                'SLU',
            ];  
        foreach ($nids as $nid) {
            $node = Node::load($nid);
            $row  = [
                'data' => [
                    $node->nid->value,
                    $node->title->value, 
                    $node->field_p_name[0]->value,
                    $node->field_ip[0]->value,
                    $node->field_p_slu[0]->value,
                ],
            ];
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        //Build the table
        $build = [
          'table'           => [
          '#prefix'        => '<h1>My Requests</h1>',
          '#theme'         => 'table',
          '#attributes'    => [
              'data-striping' => 0
          ],
          '#header' => $header,
          '#rows'   => $rows,
      ],
    ];
    //for pagination
    $build['pager'] = array(
        '#type' => 'pager'
    );

     return $build;          
}
```

But it throws an error.

> Error: Call to undefined method `Drupal\\Core\\Entity\\Query\\Sql\\Query::extend()` in
>   /var/www-drupal/modules/ga/src/Controller/MyController.php on line
>   196

Without `extendQuery`, it shows a plain table without any style.

> [image: screenshot]

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query extenders is a concept of low-level database queries. Content entities don't have that. The extenders just add the ability to do something, they don't do anything out of the box.

Both the pager and table sort functionality is built-in in entity queries. Just call `pager()` and `tableSort()` as you would do with a raw query after adding the extenders.

Comment: Hows the working of **tableSort()** ? How can i add **ASC** and **DESC** buttons to table headers?   Pager is working well .

Comment: hi how can add sorting facility to headers(with up and down arrows) like in data tables ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of sortable table with pagination.

```
$header = [
  'id' => [
    'data' => $this->t('ID'),
    'specifier' => 'nid',
  ],
  'title' => [
    'data' => $this->t('Title'),
    'specifier' => 'title',
  ],
  'created' => [
    'data' => $this->t('Created'),
    'specifier' => 'created',
    // Set default sort criteria.
    'sort' => 'desc',
  ],
  'uid' => [
    'data' => $this->t('Author'),
    'specifier' => 'uid',
  ],
];

$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');

$query = $storage->getQuery();
$query->condition('status', \Drupal\node\NodeInterface::PUBLISHED);
$query->condition('type', 'article');
$query->tableSort($header);
// Default value is 10.
$query->pager(15);
$nids = $query->execute();

$date_formatter = \Drupal::service('date.formatter');
$rows = [];
foreach ($storage->loadMultiple($nids) as $node) {
  $row = [];
  $row[] = $node->id();
  $row[] = $node->toLink();
  $created = $node->get('created')->value;
  $row[] = [
    'data' => [
      '#theme' => 'time',
      '#text' => $date_formatter->format($created),
      '#attributes' => [
        'datetime' => $date_formatter->format($created, 'custom', \DateTime::RFC3339),
      ],
    ],
  ];
  $row[] = [
    'data' => $node->get('uid')->view(),
  ];
  $rows[] = $row;
}

$build['table'] = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#empty' => $this->t('No content has been found.'),
];

$build['pager'] = [
  '#type' => 'pager',
];
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful