# Webform and MS SQL (D8)

Tags: 8

I am assisting on a D8 site being developed and need to come up to speed as my only experience with Drupal is D6. The D6 site has a custom module/form that queries MSSQL data. It's a relatively simple form that only queries and doesn't store any information. The results are returned as a list, with the ability to drill down to details on any given record. I like what I am seeing so far with the webform module and I think it might fit our needs but I could use a little advice/direction as to connecting the form to the db.

Comment: Webform is all about collecting and storing user submitted data. For data querying (with exposed forms for user filter- and sort-able results),usually the views module is used, not Webforms.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will look into that option. Just to clarify, I would be able to query an external sql server db using the views module and exposed forms?

Comment: Difficult to tell what to advise here. Maybe have a custom route, with a custom controller, in the controller query the data yourself (Drupal comes with a nice API to query database tables) and then build a custom HTML table like https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/258362/15055 to output the data?